# How to get Reminders and similar to work after daylight savings?

Tags: macos, ios, calendar, reminders

I see a bunch of threads here on the topic, but I can't find "the answer".

I have a Reminder set for every weekday at 3:25 to pick up my kid at school. After daylight savings ended, it is now reminding me at 2:25 instead. I forgot to look at my phone this time and got all the way to the school before noticing I was an hour early...

Does anyone know how to fix this? I see *many* threads on it affecting pretty much every iOS app - my mac does the same thing BTW.

Comment: Have your devices recognised the time change otherwise - clocks all auto-set overnight? Are you set to the correct time zone/country? [The US usually changes times two weeks out from everybody else] I've heard that some countries who changed their DST dates this year were not reflected in Apple's structure. I'm on GMT[BST] which hasn't seen any legislation changes since the 60s. Never had an issue with auto-time-changes at all.